# about graph of zero set of $f(x, y, z)=\left(x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}+R^{2}-r^{2}\right)^2-4 R^{2}\left(x^{2}+y^{2}\right) $

Tags: calculus, 3d

Let $f:\mathbb{R^3} \to \mathbb{R}$
$$f(x, y, z)=\left(x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}+R^{2}-r^{2}\right)^2-4 R^{2}\left(x^{2}+y^{2}\right)
$$
and $R,r \in \mathbb{R} , 0<r<R$

now define :

$Z=\{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R^3}  | f(x,y,z)=0\}$

> what is shape of $Z$ in $\mathbb{R^3}$ ? how we can draw $Z$ in $\mathbb{R^3}$  ?

first of all we must compute $Z$ :

$\left(x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}+R^{2}-r^{2}\right)^2-4 R^{2}\left(x^{2}+y^{2}\right)=0\Rightarrow $

$z^2=\pm2R\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})^2-(R^{2}-r^{2})$

note that in the other hand we have $A \subset Z$ such that ,

$A=\{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R^3}  | x^2+y^2=R^2,z^2=r^2\}$

so $Z$ must  include  two circles with radios $R$ and $z=\pm r$. now for example how we can draw $Z$ for $R=2, r=1$ or what is graph of following equation ? is this torus ?

$$z^2=\pm2  \sqrt{x^2+y^2}-(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})^2-(2^{2}-1^{2})$$

Comment: Are you familiar with cylindrical coordinates?  If so, you might want to express the equation in terms of cylindrical coordinates.

Comment: @JesseMadnick . yes ,so let $x=\rho \cos \varphi ,y=\rho \sin \varphi ,z=z$ then $z^2=\pm 2 \rho - \rho ^2 - 3 $ now what is graph of $Z$ ?

Comment: The equation $z^2 = \pm 2 \rho - \rho^2 - 3$ defines a curve in the $(z,\rho)$-plane.  Maybe you could sketch this curve, and then think about how a curve in the $(z, \rho)$-plane gives a surface in $(x,y,z)$-space.

Answer (score 2):

It is a torus

Section with plane $y=0$ are the two circles
$$x^2+z^2-2 R x=R^2-r^2 ;\; x^2+z^2+2 R x=R^2-r^2$$
the rotation of $2\pi$ of one of the two around $z$-axis gives the surface.

---

$$...$$

[image]

[image]

Comment: @amirbahadory With *Mathematica*